# Nothing happens after extracting .tar file in Python

Tags: python

I downloaded the dataset from Yelp: https://www.yelp.com/dataset which is in .tar format.

I tried the following in Python but nothing happened afterwards, am I doing anything wrong?

```
#import module
import tarfile

path = "path to file"

# open file
file = tarfile.open(path)

# extracting file
file.extractall()

file.close()
```

Comment: Did your program run to completion without error? The archive is a TGZ file - i.e., compressed TAR. I assume you've already uncompressed it. The uncompressed TAR file is ~9GB. That's going to take quite a long time to process (~40 seconds on my machine)

Comment: when I unzip the .tar file I do see the 9 GB file with the file type = "File" but I am not sure how to convert it to a readable format. Any ideas?